# Julia: Abstract-type field in struct for solving an ODE problem

Tags: struct, julia, abstract-type

I’m learning `Julia` and particularly interested in solving differential equations using the DifferentialEquations package. I’m having a trouble with understanding how to make a good type-stable struct that is integrated. For example, I have this mutable struct to be integrated.

```
mutable struct State{T} <: DEDataVector{T}
    x::Vector{T}
    r::Region
end
```

where `Region` is custom-defined abstract type: `abstract type Region end`
The role of `Region` is to parameterize my ODE function with Callback functions. For instance,

```
function myODE(du, u, p, t)
    c = getCoeff(u.r)
    du[1] = c*u[1]
end
```

which is a simplified version of my actual code but I believe it exhibits what I’m trying to say well enough. Especially, which region `r::Region` should be in at each time `t` should be determined by `t` and it must be updated properly by Callback features.

I have a bunch of concrete-type structs whose supertype is `Region`, for example

```
struct myRegion1 <: Region
    property1::Int64
    property2::Float64
    ...
end
```

and so on similarly for the other `myRegion`s. And I have well-defined overloaded functions `getCoeff(r::myRegion1), getCoeff(r::myRegion2), …` for each region. This woked fine, but I found the integration is not optimized unless I have type-stable fields in my `State` struct. It’s tested with `@code_warntype` on myODE function. Since `Region` is an abstract type, the compiler has no solid inference on type, which leads to a performance hit for the integration.

After searching for the solution for this case, I found many people suggest to rather use parametric type struct or use Union of concrete-type structs. The former one can’t be the solution for this case, because I have a mixed type for `r` in my `State` struct. For instance, say `r` is initialized to be `myRegion1`. But as the integration proceeds, it should be updated to `myRegion2` or another when Callback is called. Therefore, I must not use a parametric State struct in terms of `Region`.

The second solution seemed like it’d work, but I end up facing another problem.
First I defined a `Union` type as following:

```
const myRegions = Union{myRegion1, myRegion2, ...}
```

Then I modified the definition of my `State` struct as

```
mutable struct State{T} <: DEDataVector{T}
    x::Vector{T}
    r::myRegions
end
```

and `r` is no longer abstract type. But when I run the integration by

```
prob = ODEProblem(myODE, u0, timeSpan, p)
solve(prob, algorithm, callback=callbacks)
```

I got an unexpected error:

```
type Union has no field mutable
```

Apparently, the integrator checks whether type of every field of u is mutable or not, which is not even defined in `Union` type. So I really got stuck here… any ideas or suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks for reading this post.

Comment: It's because your system isn't concretely typed. You should make sure to concretely type the DEDataVector struct.